# What Methods to use to Weight Employees by Value Using Predetermined Categories

Tags: algorithms, sorting, structured-data

In order to determine how much value employees provide to a company, I want to build a system that goes beyond basic math in terms of sorting said employees.  I'm working with values like current salary, number of people working under them, and a value from 1-3 of how indispensable they are to the company.  What methods should I use to construct a weighting system, so the allotments of value aren't just completely subjective?

*note - I'm not asking for a perfect method, just something that helps improve my accuracy on determining value.

Comment: I guess this question should be asked on statistics forum.

Comment: This is not really a question about computer science. What is the goal of sorting employees? Are you trying to predict which employee is the "best"? The only way to bring math in is if you want to predict the employee's performance (in some quantitatively fixed way) given their "traits", and then you can use machine learning approaches.